# "Change Directory" Command doesn't work in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I'm learning python by myself on my Mac. I downloaded a folder  to my desktop called ExercisesFiles and it has a subfolder called Chap01. And Chap01 has a python file called 01_03.py. Now I open a Mac terminal and tried to write some commands to open the 01_03.py file. I wrote down:

> cd Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01

Then the terminal tells me:

> -bash: cd: Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01: No such file or directory

I can't figure out why the terminal doesn't allow me to change directory? I look up the Mac terminal commands and I believe my commands are right. Thank you.

Comment: Use `ls` to see the directories and files in your current directory. There might be a typo (in the text, you write `ExercisesFiles`, in the command you use `ExerciseFiles`). Use tab completion (hit the tab key after you've typed the first few characters) to let the shell complete the directory and filenames for you.

Comment: try to do folder by folder, and than when it doesn't allow you to go further or throws some errors, use ls to see the folder inside the current folder

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've tried "ls" but it keeps return all the stuff on my desktop, which means that the "change directory" command is not working. B/c the directory is still the "Desktop".

Comment: @VivHuang That indicates you're already in your Desktop directory. `cd Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01` means "from where I am, go down into the `Desktop` subdirectory, then `ExerciseFiles` under that, then `Chap01` under that. It's looking for a `Desktop` subfolder, but you're already there! From in your Desktop directory, you could use `cd ExerciseFiles/Chap01`. On the other hand, `cd ~/Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01` will work no matter where you're starting from, because it ignores your current directory and starts from your home directory.

Comment: Thank you! I totally understand it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform `pwd` for checking current working directory. Maybe you're not in user's home dir.
If you want to go to `Desktop` from any place, you can exec `cd ~/Desktop/`. 
In this case, `~` makes sure that you're in logged-in-user's home dir.
Adjust this command accordingly for your needs.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? So now I close the terminal and reopen it. Then I entered `cd ~Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01`, it returns `zsh: no such user or named directory: Desktop`. Then I entered `pwd`, it returns `/Users/vivhuang`. Then I entered `cd ~Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01`, it returns `zsh: no such user or named directory: Desktop`. Then I entered `cd ~/Desktop/ExerciseFiles/Chap01`, it returns nothing. So I entered `ls` and the python file come out! Can you please explain a little bit what happens? I'm still not 100% clear about how it works. Thx.

Comment: Please use `~/Desktop` not `~Desktop`.